# TypeScript: How to solve 'property does not exist for type' error for arrays?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to TypeScript/React. I am getting an error for the following when trying to pass props as an array to a component.

I am calling the component as such:

```
return <ContactInfoBlock contactInfo={contact} />;
```

where `contact` is an array of information, eg:

```
const contact = {
  contactName: 'Jim',
  contactAvatar: 'jim.png',
  contactEmail: 'jim@jim.com',
  contactPhone: '1234 4566',
};
```

And on my component file I have:

```
type ContactInfoInterface = {
  contactName: string;
  contactEmail: string;
  contactPhone: string;
};

interface ContactInfoBlockProps {
  contactInfo: ContactInfoBlock[];
}

const ContactInfoBlock = ({ contactInfo }: ContactInfoBlockProps) => {

 return (
   <Typography variant="h6">
     {contactInfo.contactName}
   </Typography>
   //etc
```

This works - the data actually appears on the front end. But I get the warning:

> Property 'contactName' does not exist on type
>   'ContactInfoInterface[]'.  TS2339

According to the tutorials I've followed, this should work. But I still get the error.

Would anyone know what I could do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This works - the date actually appears on the front end

This means your TypeScript signature is wrong.

## Fix

It should be:

```
interface ContactInfoBlockProps {
  contactInfo: ContactInfoBlock;
}
```

i.e. it is *not an array* as `contactInfo.contactName` is working at runtime